# Expected FS format '2' found format '3 git-svn

Tags: svn, git, version-control, git-svn

I was just checking out git-svn and thought I would give it a try with one of my existing repository.  When I ran git-svn I got this error.

Couldn't open a repository: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL: Unable to
 open repository '{MyFilePath}': **Expected FS format '2';
found format '3'** at C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git-svn line 1358

I ran a version check on git-svn that I am using and it printed out:

```
git-svn version 1.5.5.1015.g9d258 (svn 1.4.6)
```

I noticed that it's using svn version 1.4.6 but I created the repositry using TortoiseSVN with Svn version Subversion 1.5.1.

My main question is how do I update git-svn so that it will use 1.5?

Comment: Your git version is pretty old, too. Especially on windows (which is what you are using it seems), there have been a lot of fixes since then. I would try updating git first.

Comment: I am running  1.6.3.msysgit.0 which still has svn 1.4.6 so you need to have svnserve running.

Comment: btw, the latest preview version of msysgit (1.7.3.1) still has this problem, so the age of git install is not the issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you access your Subversion repository using a network protocol (such as `svn://`) instead of local file access, then things should work properly for you. It appears as though you're asking `git-svn` to access the repository directly, causing the problem you've shown. The Subversion network protocols are more resilient to older clients connecting.

Comment: now I'm getting a "Connection refused: Can't connect to host '': Connection refused at" error.  Any ideas what would be could causing that.

Comment: In order to connect with the svn:// protocol, you will need an instance of svnserve running on port 3690 (default). See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s03.html for more information about setting up svnserve.

Comment: To answer your next question before you need to ask, you will also need to set up the "passwd" and "svnserve.conf" files in the conf/ subdirectory of your repository with appropriate access credentials before you will be able to commit anything with git-svn. The svnserve daemon by default allows anonymous read-only access, with credentials required for write. You may alternately set up "anon-access = write" in svnserve.conf if your machine is on a private network (ie. nobody else can connect to it).

Comment: Cool thanks for the help, setting it up now.  I managed to get it to pull down the files but I didn't try and commit it so I didn't run into that issue, so thanks for the heads up.

Comment: That might be a solution for some people, but it doesn't answer the question asked. What if I can't switch to svnserve (e.g., if my team accesses the Subversion repository via a network filesystem)?

Answer (score 12):

I encountered this problem when I wanted quickly test some behaviour of git-svn and thus needed an svn repository.

I created repository with following command:

```
svnadmin create --pre-1.4-compatible
```

git is able to understand such repositories.